# Build Gradle + Proguard + APKLib

Tags: android, build, gradle, obfuscation, proguard

I developed an Android Library, used by a test Application that I developed as well.

I need to obfuscate the code of the Android Library, to be able to deliver it to some clients, without them being able to see too much of the code.
But I need to have as a result an Android Library, with the same Structure as my Non obfuscated Library, so that I can still open it with Eclipse and use it in other applications.

I've tried to do it with Gradle and then Proguard, but I'm having a hard time there.

First, I used the plugin : "android-library" to build my apklib, but I can't really well understand the structure of the folders created under the build folder.

Which folder is supposed to contain the new Android Library Project with obfuscated classes?
Am I doin it the right way?

Moreover I'm having a hard time, because many of the original classes don't seem to be generated and are missing once I made the build, but I can't really figure out why, what are the possibles reasons for this?

Is it possible that it could be because of some deprecated method used, or something like that?

My last question is about the correct way to import Library during the build, my Android Library is using some external jars to work, but if I inspect the output during the build, I can see that I seem to be losing most of the original library classes :

16:36:33.809 [INFO] [system.out]   Original number of library classes: 5366
16:36:33.809 [INFO] [system.out]   Final number of library classes:    615

What could cause that?
I know my question is pretty vague, but I've been struggling for a day with this and can't really improve my build for now.
Any help or advice on how to properly build an Android Library with obfuscation with Gradle and Proguard would be greatly appreciated.

Edit :

I found some kind of related posts, but nothing is really clear about the output generated by Gradle Using Proguard. It seems that the attend output is the .aar file under the lib folder, but that's not really what I was looking for.
So far, I kind of succeeded by using some special rules in my Proguard settings file to force some of my files to be kept with the -keep rule (but I can't really undertand why they're not kept and obfuscated if I don't put these rules). Then I used the classes.jar generated in the bundles/release folder, and moved it into a new Android Library Project libs folder, copying the resources from my original Android Library Project. Makes me an Android Library Project with obfuscated sources, but doesn't seems very clean.

Comment: Any update on this? As you mentioned in your response to Ashwin, almost everyone, including Xavier and Eric Lafortune, are affirmative about what they think you should do ("Android libraries are not obfuscated; Apps are obfuscated"), instead of answering your question ("How do I obfuscate my Android library"). Google obviously obfuscates their Android libraries (Maps, Analytics, etc), so how is this done? Using DexGuard?

Answer (score 1):

First of all **you can not open your obfuscated code in eclipse.since obfuscation process will not generate the project structure which you want to open in eclipse.Obfuscation is a process to secure your binary distributed code not the source code.Please keep this clear 
in your mind.**

I think you need to do binary distribution of your android library project.For binary distribution of android library projects extension used is aar as mentioned in the [AAR FORMAT](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)

It means that you need to look for yourlibrary.aar file generated under build folder. For android library projects do not obfuscate your code. Since it will be difficult for your clients to consume library.

You will get the .aar file in your build/outputs/aar folder.

I think this is  quite enough to go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time. As I said in my post, I already kwnow about the AAR library generated, but this is not really what I want to get. I'm a bit tired about people not really reading the questions, or being so affirmative about what I need to do. 
I know too that I need to keep the entry points of my Library not obfuscated so that it would be usable by my clients.
Anyway, thanks for the reminder of what obfuscation is really for. I understood it wont give me a project that I could be able to use in Eclipse. But keep in mind that all clients won't be able to use an AAR library.